# Can I use CSS Modules with Storybook 5 (React flavour)?

Tags: webpack, css-modules, storybook, react-css-modules

I am trying to use Storybook v5.0 with my project and I am using React + Webpack4 + CSS Modules. ( I am not using CreateReactApp)

My setup is quite simple, and I was able to setup Storybook without CSS modules fine.

However if I try to edit the custom storybook webpack config to support CSS modules, it errors.

When I run `npm run storybook` the error I get is:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/Test/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/style-loader!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./src/components/Test/index.css)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(2:1) Unknown word

  1 |
> 2 | var content = require("!!../../../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--9-1!../../../node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js!./index.css");
    | ^
  3 |
  4 | if(typeof content === 'string') content = [[module.id, content, '']];
```

In my `package.json`:

```
"@storybook/addon-actions": "^5.0.0",
"@storybook/addons": "^5.0.0",
"@storybook/react": "^5.0.0",
```

My `.storybook/webpack.config.js` follows the example on their web site, and looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");

const stylesLoaders = [
  "style-loader",
  {
    loader: "css-loader",
    options: {
      modules: true,
      localIdentName: "[path]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]"
    }
  },
  "postcss-loader"
];

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        loaders: stylesLoaders,
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I'd like to use the latest version of Storybook!

Comment: Hey, I'm struggling with the same issue.. Got any solution ? @Saldog

Comment: If you want to use full control mode you probably have to remove some default rules that collide with yours. Follow this example here and the whole conversation: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/issues/5941#issuecomment-471174523

Answer (score 5):

This is what worked for me:

```js
// ./.storybook/main.js
module.exports = {
  //
  webpackFinal: (config, {configType}) => {
    const path  = require('path');

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.css$/,
      use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader?modules=true'],
      include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../'),
    });
    
    return config;
  }
  //
}
```

## AND

#### *Renaming* my `CSS` files from `<filename>.css` to `<filename>.module.css`.

Good Luck...

Comment: `css-loader?modules=true` is a nice shortcut for configuring options. thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the new storybook ( v5 ). Finally i made it work after i had to spread config and config.module in the .storybook/webpack.config.js

Accordingly with Storybook's documentation, i used a function for webpack rather than an object:  https://storybook.js.org/docs/configurations/custom-webpack-config/

Here is an exemple :

```
module.exports = ({ config }) => ({
  ...config,
  module: {
    ...config.module,
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use:[
          {
            loader: require.resolve("babel-loader"),
            options: {
            presets: [["react-app", { flow: false, typescript: true }]]
            }
          }
        ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: "style-loader",
            options: { sourceMap: true }
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              importLoaders: 1,
              modules: true,
              localIdentName: "[name]__[local]__[hash:base64:5]"
            }
          },
          {
            loader: require.resolve("postcss-loader"),
            options: {
              ident: "postcss",
              plugins: () => [
                require("postcss-flexbugs-fixes"),
                require("postcss-inline-svg"),
                require("postcss-svgo"),
                autoprefixer({
                  browsers: [
                    ">1%",
                    "last 4 versions",
                    "Firefox ESR",
                    "not ie < 9"
                  ],
                  flexbox: "no-2009"
                })
              ]
            }
          }
        ],
        include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../")
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not post question as answer. As you may not have enough reputation to comment, you could upvote the question

Comment: Look like the post is not correctly edited to be an answer.
Please don't downvote since is a possible valid answer like is explained in the official storybook change log: https://github.com/storybooks/storybook/blob/next/MIGRATION.md#from-version-501-to-502

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with the new storybook (v6). Finally, I am able to resolve the error when I applied this solution

https://github.com/GVanderLugt/storybook-next-antd-less-typescript-config/blob/master/.storybook/next-preset.js

Many thanks to him!

Comment: This was a big help–thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

[How to use css-modules with storybook 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70042915/how-to-use-css-modules-with-storybook-6/72398680#72398680)

#### Installation

```
npm install -D storybook-css-modules
```

#### Configuration

Next, update .storybook/main.js to the following:

```
// .storybook/main.js

module.exports = {
  stories: [
    // ...
  ],
  addons: [
    // Other Storybook addons

    "storybook-css-modules", //  The addon registered here
  ],
};
```